# Efficiently loading/importing a big dataset that is in a non-standard format into R

Tags: r, csv, bigdata, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

The code used in this question comes from the script entitled "LASSO code (Version for Antony) in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) for this research project.

I am trying to load each of the 260,000 csv file-formatted datasets (each of which is 189 KB) into my RStudio environment/WorkSpace sequentially using the following code:

```
# load all necessary packages using only 1 command/line
library_list <- c(library(plyr),library(dplyr),library(tidyverse),
                  library(readr),library(stringi),library(purrr),
                  library(stats),library(leaps),library(lars),
                  library(elasticnet),library(data.table),library(parallel),
                  library(microbenchmark))

# these 2 lines together create a simple character list of 
# all the file names in the file folder of datasets you created
folderpath <- "C:/Users/Spencer/Documents/EER Project/datasets folder"
filepaths_list <- list.files(path = folderpath, full.names = TRUE, 
                             recursive = TRUE)
# reformat the names of each of the csv file formatted datasets
DS_names_list <- basename(filepaths_list)
DS_names_list <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(DS_names_list)

# sort both of the list of file names so that they are in the proper order
my_order = DS_names_list |> 
  # split apart the numbers, convert them to numeric 
  strsplit(split = "-", fixed = TRUE) |>  unlist() |> as.numeric() |>
  # get them in a data frame
  matrix(nrow = length(DS_names_list), byrow = TRUE) |> as.data.frame() |>
  # get the appropriate ordering to sort the data frame
  do.call(order, args = _)

DS_names_list = DS_names_list[my_order]
filepaths_list = filepaths_list[my_order]

# this line reads all of the data in each of the csv files 
# using the name of each store in the list we just created
CL1 <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1L)
clusterExport(CL1, c('filepaths_list'))
system.time( datasets <- parLapply(CL1, filepaths_list, fread) )
stopCluster(CL1)
```

Note: this 'datasets folder' is 46.6 GB.
I calculated that it should take around 36ish hours to finish based on loading a 1000 dataset folder using the same script before hand. However, around 25 hours into the process (or before), when I woke up on Thursday morning, my laptop had frozen. I waited all afternoon and tried everything to resuscitate it, but it was frozen solid.

Is there any syntactic error I made in my code here? My laptop is only several months old, with a 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1155G7 @ 2.50GHz processor, two fully compatible 16 GB ram sticks for a total of 32 gb of RAM, and also, a fast after market 1 tb SSD, so I don't see why my laptop shouldn't be able to pull this off so long as I am patient enough to wait.

p.s.
I tried the same operation several days earlier with all lines of code the same except the actual command to load the file folder in, that time it was the following:

```
CL <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1L)
clusterExport(CL, c('filepaths_list'))
system.time( datasets <- lapply(filepaths_list, read.csv) )
```

However, after around 56 hours in of waiting, I realized I made a mistake but forgetting to do the following instead:

```
system.time( datasets <- parLapply(CL, filepaths_list, read.csv) )
```

Or preferably, read_csv instead, so I cancelled that operation, but my laptop did not freeze that time.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are trying to load 46gb of data into 32gb of ram?

Comment: No, 46 GB worth of data on observations when I have about 280 GB left in storage using my 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: When you say "280 GB left in storage" do you mean your hard-drive? R by default loads data into ram memory e.g. not the hard drive. It can use swao memory for some things (slow) but I dont know of such stuffs. Are you able to read the data in and process in chunks?

Comment: @user20650 all I know is each time I am hitting run, as it is running, the amount of space left in my SSD goes down substantially and continuously.

Comment: It's possible some other OS program has mounted tmpfs, but only because it is swapping to disk (and your RAM is full)

Comment: Given that you have a CSV file, it may be better to import into a database first... Sqlite, MariaDB, Postgtes, DuckDB, etc... Then process it

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have used MySQL Workbench in the past, good idea!

Comment: That'll potentially also reduce the dataset size, if imported with correct types rather than all strings, but you still will not want to `SELECT *` into an in-memory table without `LIMIT`

Comment: @OneCricketeer that string part is the main problem I have discovered so far which I should have noticed up front. When working with just 20k of the datasets right now, after running the lines that convert all of the observations from strings to numbers/floats, the size reduced from like 23 GB to 2 GB!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250915/discussion-between-spencer-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: Sounds like you solved it? Feel free to post your solution below

Comment: @OneCricketeer I really wish it were true, I actually gave up and started running my code on 10k worth of the 260k datasets at a time which is really tedious, but it will only take maybe 2 to 2 and a half days to complete this way by my back of the envelope calculations which is better than wasting another week trying and failing to do it all at once. I even tried to figure it out using AWS, but I have never used AWS before had absolutely no idea what I was using to the point where I couldn't even connect my server or instance or whatever it is called!